# GitHub API, posting new comment using a variable

Tags: bash, github, github-api

I have a file with a bunch of output from some performance tests. It looks similar to the following:

```
index | master | performance-fix | change %
--- | --- | --- | ---
load | 26212.8 | 28223.6 | 7.67%
type | 67.5 | 75.41 | 11.72%
minType | 56.91 | 59.6 | 4.73%
maxInserterSearch | 185.45 | 283.25 | 52.74%
minInserterHover | 25.97 | 27.55 | 6.08%
maxInserterHover | 44.47 | 44.7 | 0.52%
```

I am trying to submit a new comment on a Github issue using that table data. Standard text works fine, but when I try and pass the table along I'm getting the error:

```
{
  "message": "Problems parsing JSON",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/issues#update-an-issue-comment"
}
```

My cURL request is as follows:

```
NEW_COMMENT=$(curl -sS \
  -X PATCH \
  -u $GH_LOGIN:$GH_AUTH_TOKEN \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
  "https://api.github.com/repos/$CIRCLE_PROJECT_USERNAME/$CIRCLE_PROJECT_REPONAME/issues/comments/$COMMENT_ID" \
  -d '{"body": "Results: <br />'"$TEST_RESULTS"'"}')
```

I have also tried creating the `{"body": ...}` using jq, and using the `--data-urlencode` flag. Both return the same "Problems parsing JSON" error.

Comment: Single quoted strings do not interpolate variables. See [3.1.2 Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Quoting) in the manual

Comment: It's likely because your `TEST_RESULTS` contains newline characters. Post process it by for instance replacing `\n` with `<br>` and try again.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `$TEST_RESULTS` contains characters that make the JSON not what you think it is, like including quotation marks and newlines

Maybe escaping the JSON output like [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/548892/how-to-json-escape-input) will help

```sh
escaped="$(printf '%s' "$TEST_RESULTS" | jq -Rs '.')"

... \
-d '{"body": "Results: <br />'"$escaped"'"}')
```